# Code-Generation utility to generate java template to visit all the methods and object (Nested)

Tags: java, code-generation

I need to generate java template code to access the nested object with structure.

for eg:

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private List<Address> address;

}

class Address{
    private String doorNo;
    private String Address;
    private City city;
}

class City{
    ....
}
```

So a method is required which will take any object(Nested) and generate the java code for  above person object as follows.

```
//Generated java code should be like this
if(person != null){
    String name = StringUtils.isEmpty(Person.getName());
    if(person.getAdressList() != null && person.getAddressLit().isNotEmpty()){

        for (Address address : person.getAdressList()) {
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

The method should be generic and generate code recursively for dynamic nested object.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Add the code you tried, and why it is not working. We won't write that for you...

Comment: Do you really want to generate java code (e.g. a .java file), or do you want to traverse your data structure using reflection?

Comment: Have a look at the Java Annotation Processing Tool, it has functionality to traverse through java code and generate new one. But keep in mind that this is a developer-time consuming task.

Comment: Need a java file which in turn traverse through the Object structure. Any tool or an API to achieve this in quicker.

Comment: As an afternote: You may find it useful to ask this (and similar) questions on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code generation is a complicated task and can't be fully answered in the Q&A Format of StackOverflow.

Keep in mind that while writing a function that "just" creates the method you describe here would take about a day or so. Maybe writing it from hand, though boring, is the more time efficient approach. (http://xkcd.com/1205/)

If you want to generate code you first have to pick a code generation tool that does what you need. There are several (maybe you can use the refactoring functions of your IDE as well). If you want to be able to manipulate the way the code is processed within the original source code, I have found the [Java APT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) to be very useful. It will let you traverse `packages` of Java code and generate classes and methods according to the structure found therein.
It is a tool that can interpret `Annotations` to be able to determinate what to do with any single method.

Comment: Ya i understand the complexity. The best of part of it will bug free and we concentrate on BL rather than repeating the same process. Because we have around (45 * 3) nested object. I am looking for api or tool which helps me to achieve this in efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JetBrains MPS. That's a metaprogramming IDE with Java as a first-class target.
http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/

Another approach would be to develop a Spring Roo plugin.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/